# How to remove a JSON object in an array with Python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, scripting

Using Python3, I have a JSON output stored in a variable. The output contains something like this:

```
    {
    "department": "inventory",
    "products": [
        {
            "color": "red",
            "shape": "circle",
            "size": "large"
        },
        {
            "color": "blue",
            "shape": "square",
            "size": "small"
        },
        {
            "color": "green",
            "shape": "triangle",
            "size": "medium"
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to remove any object, within the "products" array, that have a value for "size" as "large" or "medium", leaving with a new output of:

```
    {
    "department": "inventory",
    "products": [
        {
            "color": "blue",
            "shape": "square",
            "size": "small"
        },
    }
```

I am somewhat successful using a combination of a for statement with an if statement outside of the array using pop, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it just for the objects within the products array.

I have tried the following:

```
    for element in products
     if last_login[i]["size"] == "medium":
         del element
```

Which just gives me this:

```
    KeyError: 0
```

Please feel free to ask more questions if needed,

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: without some work of your own no coding service, look for list comprehension in the doc

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.

Comment: Yes - apologies... I just updated it with what I tried earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of deleting you can just filter and reassign

```
import json

d = json.loads(json_data)
d['products'] = [x for x in d['products'] if x['size'] not in ('large', 'medium')]
```

Comment: Hello - is there a benefit to doing it this way? Wouldn't this create 2 arrays or am I missing something? If you have some literature on this that I can read that would be awesome! Thx

Comment: it just an implementation choice. It's better to create new list instead of deleting elements from list

Comment: Ok understood! what does the d before the list variable do and mean? I keep getting "NameError: name 'd' is not defined"

Comment: @Awsmike It's parsed json stored in a variable named `d`